# Rails CSRF protection and Cache-Control: public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, http-caching

I have added the following to my application's layout file in order that I can enable public HTTP caching of certain pages.

```
= csrf_meta_tag unless response.cache_control[:public]
```

I can do this because the app is generated using Backbone preloaded with JSON that doesn't change from one user to the next.

```
render json: [some, list, of, public, things]
expires_in 10.minutes, public: true
```

However, I want to be able to submit POST requests from these cached pages for login and purchasing.  Must I choose between having a fast (cached) site on one hand and a secure one (per-session csrf tokens) on the other?

Comment: alternate solution: fragment caching

Comment: Actually, I think I may solve this with my /api/user.json action which is sessions-specific and so could deliver the csrf-token to the JS app. Should have mentioned that..